# SharePoint list calculated column compare dates

Tags: sharepoint, wss-3.0

I've got a field in a SharePoint list that multiplies a number of miles someone enters in one column with the current reimbursement rate for mileage.

It ends up like this:
=[Mileage] * 0.51

With the rates now going up I need to increase that, but only for rates entered after a certain date. This should be ok because we capture the entry date. However, I can not get it to work.

Doing something like this:
=IF([Date] < "7/1/2011", [Mileage] * 0.51, [Mileage] * 0.555)

Does not seem to work, as the first equation always triggers. I'm assuming I'm missing something simple like converting the string to a date, but can not find it after searching.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [SharePoint function you're looking for is DATE(year,month,day)](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-sharepoint-services-help/date-function-HA001160980.aspx)

So this gives (assuming your orig date was US format so 1st July 2011)

```
=IF([Date] < Date(2011,7,1), [Mileage] * 0.51, [Mileage] * 0.555)
```

*Self promotion - but this [SharePoint Calculated Column Cheat Sheet](http://blog.pentalogic.net/2011/05/sharepoint-calculated-column-cheat-sheet/) may help you if you're doing lots of calculated column stuff.*